# Trouble adding values to ManyToMany field Django 1.9

Tags: django, django-models, manytomanyfield

Before this is flagged, I have vigorously researched this problem and none of the solutions I have found have worked for me.

Here is my model

```
class Person():
    birth_date = models.DateField(null=False)
    jobs = models.ManyToManyField('Job', blank=True)
```

Here is what I'm doing to try to add to the ManyToMany field

```
person = Person(birth_date="1996-11-11")
person.save()
```

Everything works fine with the initial save. Then I try to add to the jobs field doing the following

```
job = get_object_or_404(Job, pk=1)
person.jobs.add(job)
```

I've also tried the following as a test:

```
person.jobs.add(1)
```

No such luck with either. The error is:

```
TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'instancemethod'
```

even when I tried to give it a pk directly as an integer.

Any help on why this may be happening would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is error adding it with `person.jobs.add(job)`. Did you make sure you did not get 404 error?

Comment: can add the person class and job class model. it seems like you have job as function , please check job type.

Comment: Please show the *full* traceback.